# Where does lightning strike?

Tags: lightning

While watching lightning activity in the sky from afar, a natural curiosity welled within me. What are the exact locations where those lightning bolts strike?

All these questions appear because of my ignorance of this natural phenomenon. I hope any lightning experts out there can help me understand, what exactly makes a spot a possible candidate for the lightning to strike? Has a list all past lightning-struck locations been compiled?

Comment: Please check the answers in: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/580/why-does-lightning-strike-from-the-ground-up

Comment: I believe https://what-if.xkcd.com/16/ had some absolutely fantastic explanation and science.  I can't absolutely vouch for every bit of it, as it wasn't a particularly subfield of study, but all of it looks very reasonable from this degreed-meteorologist's perspective.