# Why is lightning going from the Earth to the clouds while the electrons are going from the clouds to the Earth?

Tags: meteorology

The lightning is often a discharge in advance. The (negative) charge slide occasionally a little further on in the conductive channel, wherein said channel is highlighted each time something. The lowering speed of the discharge is "only" about 1,500 kilometers per second.

The main discharge provides the lightning that we usually perceive (which appears from the clouds to the earth, but not in reality). After the discharge of this strong flow fills the entire channel. This is called the main discharge or sometimes the 'backlash' (return stroke).

This phenomenon, with intense light accompanied, moves at about 100,000 to 150,000 km / s from the earth to the cloud. In this situation, the electrons move down and our speech becomes the current direction counted up. After all, the electric current runs from plus to minus, as opposed to the electrons.

But the question now is how electrons that emerge give a flash of light which goes up?

See also : [Why does lightning strike from the ground-up?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/580/why-does-lightning-strike-from-the-ground-up)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. In slow motion videos you see the main flash of light going DOWN as well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MUYsIjTKvk

Comment: I've watched the video but I can't see that the main flash is going down.

Comment: It does both. More often, the downward arc is the stronger one. See [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8waV48897o4) for a much clearer view of a whole bunch of strikes.

Comment: I think it is still to fast to see the strongest light going down.